# Lower bounding the probability that a submartingale passes a threshold

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, stopping-times

Suppose $X_t$ is a submartingale, with the property that it has "large enough" increments:
$$\mathbb{E}[X_{t+1}-X_t|X_t] \geq \exp(-X_t^2/t),$$
and it is *not* uniformly bounded, but each $X_t$ is bounded.

For a given threshold $\theta$ define the stopping time $\tau = \inf\{t: X_t \geq \theta\}$. The goal is to lower bound the probability $\Pr\{\tau \leq T\}$.

The intuition behind this question is that if the submartingale increases enough, it will pass "small enough" thresholds with high probability and in small time.

Comment: The main issue is that all inequalities (like Doob's maximal inequality) are for the converse, they upper bound the probability that the submartingale passes a threshold in a given timespan.